# Chartjs polararea ticks label getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using the polarArea chart from chartjs for displaying my data.
But my tick label gets overlapped by color.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'polarArea',
      data: {
        labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5'],
        datasets: [{
          data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
          backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56', '#4BC0C0', '#9966FF']
        }]
      },
      options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scale: {
          pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 14,
            fontColor: 'black',
            fontStyle: 'normal',
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return value + '°'; // Add a degree symbol to the tick labels
            }
          }
        },
        plugins: [{
          afterUpdate: function(chart) {
            var ticks = chart.scales.r.ticks; // Get the tick values from the r scale
            var pointLabels = chart.scales.r.pointLabels; // Get the point labels from the r scale
            var radius = chart.scales.r.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(ticks[ticks.length-1]); // Get the radius of the outermost tick
            var offset = 50; // Set the desired offset value

            for (var i = 0; i < pointLabels.length; i++) {
              var angleRadians = chart.config.options.scale.angleLines.lineWidth * i;
              var x = radius * Math.cos(angleRadians) + offset;
              var y = radius * Math.sin(angleRadians) + offset;
              pointLabels[i].x = x;
              pointLabels[i].y = y;
            }
          }
        }],
        // other chart configurations...
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="400"></canvas>
```

How to move tick labels slightly to make them more visible.
Using  dark colours, which create difficulty .  
I want to position as shown in image .[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched all options and it appears there's no simple way to this. Except the way that is too simple - adding space characters in front of the label text in `options.scales.r.ticks.callback`.

The solution below is based on creating a custom axis class, deriving from `RadialLinearScale` and overriding only its `drawLabels` to translate the canvas context before the standard label drawing operation and restoring it for all other uses. I don't think these methods are documented, but can be identified quite easily in the high quality source code of charts.js

I also adjusted the option object keys for some of the original options, to work in this environment.

```js
class TranslatedLabelsScale extends Chart.RadialLinearScale{
    static id = 'linearRadialWithLabelTranslations';
    drawLabels(){
        const translation = this.options.ticks?.labelTranslation || {};
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate(translation.x || 0, translation.y || 0);
        super.drawLabels();
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
}
Chart.register(TranslatedLabelsScale);

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
        labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56', '#4BC0C0', '#9966FF']
        }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            r: {
                //startAngle: 20,
                type: 'linearRadialWithLabelTranslations',
                ticks: {
                    padding: 10,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: '#000',
                    fontStyle: 'normal',
                    labelTranslation: {x: 20, y: 0},
                    z: 10,
                    backdropColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
                    callback: function(value, index, values){
                        // poor man's solution: return '     '+value + '°'
                        return value + '°'; // Add a degree symbol to the tick labels
                    }
                }
            }
        }, // other chart configurations...
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```